# 8-bit PIC Microcontrollers plus sensors

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I have been looking at the PIC16F1615 - 8-bit Microcontroller and have been wondering what Temperature Sensors would be compatible with this controller. As you can probably tell I'm very new to microcontrollers.

**Specifications**

Program Memory Type / Flash 
Program Memory (KB) / 14 
CPU Speed (MIPS) / 8  
RAM Bytes / 1,024 
Digital Communication Peripherals / 1-UART, 1-SPI, 1-I2C 
Capture/Compare/PWM Peripherals / 2 CCP 
Timers / 4 x 8-bit, 3 x 16-bit 
Comparators / 2 
Temperature Range (C) / -40 to 125 
Operating Voltage Range (V) / 1.8 to 5.5 
Pin Count / 14 
XLP / Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That part has SPI, I2C and ADCs so any single device you find that has and I2C or SPI interface will work. Also, anything with an analogue output will work if you connect it to an ADC input, get the ADC value and convert it to temperature in software.

SPI or I2C would be the way I'd do it. There are myriad devices out there that will do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

As DiBosco suggested any temperature sensor with SPI or I2C interface can be used and analog temperature sensors can also be used since chip has ADC support.

If you want to know which specific temperature sensor can meet your needs, then you should mention what application you are planning to implement.

For example if you are aiming to build a power supply temperature monitoring TMP100/TMP101 from Texas instruments and LM75 from Maxim are good suggestion. ADT7420 from Analog devices is a high precision temperature sensor. All the three have I2C interface.

TMP35/TMP36/TMP37 and LM35 are good analog temperature sensors. Just go through the data sheets and choose one that fits your requirement. And of course there are other good sensors available in the market and you can find them in quick web search. All the best.